# Optimization of filter & loops to run on 1M rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to run a query with multiple filters on a data frame

Works like a charm on my small sample (below) but takes a lot of time as data increases.

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'ID': [FACL01, FACL02, FACL03, FACL01, FACL04, FACL06, FACL07, 
                        FACL08, FACL09, FACL01, FACL11, FACL12], 
                 'AMOUNT': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 20, 10, 30, 10], 
                 'DATE': [20201503, 20201503, 20201503, 20201502, 20201503, 20201502, 
                          20201501, 20201503, 20201503, 20201501, 20201503, 20201502]})
df[AVG_AMOUNT]=0

%%time
for idx, x in df['ID'].iteritems():
df.loc[idx, 'AVG_AMOUNT']=(df[(df['DATE'].isin(M1)) & (df.ID==x)]['AMOUNT'].mean())
```

I am trying to get average of all `AMOUNT` within `3 month period (M1)` for a particular `ID` to fill in `AVG_AMOUNT`.

Comment: Rolling operations are usually slow, but you could turn your `DATE` column into `datetime` format and then research how to perform a 3 month rolling average. Else, you could perform a 3 row rolling average, if you're sure you will never miss dates in your dataframe

Comment: Actually, the time period is fixed. i.e. 3 months. I don't think converting the date would make it run any quicker.

Comment: If the data is as presented `df.groupby(['ID', 'DATE']).AMOUNT.rolling(3).mean()` should suffice

Comment: @hpaulj: Why did you remoive the "dataframe" tag? Tthe question clearly concerns them.

Comment: @martineau, someone else removed `dataframe`.  I added `pandas`.  In python `pandas` is virtually synonymous with `dataframe`.  I think the major imports are the most important tags.

Comment: The dataframe tag returns

Comment: Not being funny, why not put the data into a database (MySQL?) and query the database instead.  More flexible and interfaces nicely with a DataFrame.

Comment: @Juan C : Groupby creates a frame so populating data in the column with correct indexing becomes difficult. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @S3DEV That's would work but in my case I can't. Otherwise would have used SQLLite. PySpark seems to be the only viable option right now.

Comment: What's your problem with indexing? Your index will become `ID` and `DATE`, so they'll be easy to track

Comment: @Juan C: Sorry I didn't get you, can you give an example??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your data a bit, because you provided as many `ID`'s as rows, which would make rolling means futile. I reduced it to 2 IDs, but the rest is the same:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['FACL01', 'FACL01', 'FACL01', 'FACL01', 'FACL04',
                        'FACL04', 'FACL04', 'FACL04', 'FACL04', 'FACL04'
                        , 'FACL04', 'FACL04'], 
                 'AMOUNT': [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 20, 10, 30, 10], 
                 'DATE': [20201503, 20201503, 20201503, 20201502, 20201503, 20201502, 
                          20201501, 20201503, 20201503, 20201501, 20201503, 20201502]})

df = df.sort_values(['ID','DATE']) #Sort for clarity
dfgroup = df.groupby(['ID', 'DATE']).AMOUNT.sum().rolling(3, min_periods=1).mean()
```

### Output:

```
ID      DATE    
FACL01  20201502     40.0
        20201503     50.0
FACL04  20201501     60.0
        20201502     70.0
        20201503    110.0
```

If you want to add this to your dataframe you could do something like:

```
dfgroup.name = 'Average_Amount'
df = df.merge(dfgroup.reset_index())
```

#### Output 2:

```
        ID  AMOUNT      DATE  Average_Amount
0   FACL01      40  20201502            40.0
1   FACL01      10  20201503            50.0
2   FACL01      20  20201503            50.0
3   FACL01      30  20201503            50.0
4   FACL04      70  20201501            60.0
5   FACL04      10  20201501            60.0
6   FACL04      60  20201502            70.0
7   FACL04      10  20201502            70.0
8   FACL04      50  20201503           110.0
9   FACL04      80  20201503           110.0
10  FACL04      20  20201503           110.0
11  FACL04      30  20201503           110.0
```

Comment: This looks perfect, the only thing is that I have dates from 2018-01-01 to 2019-01-01, can rolling accommodate that? Earlier I was creating an array of dates and putting it as a where clause; `df[df[date.isin(array)]].groupby……`

Comment: It shouldn't matter. You'll have a problem if you have missing dates, though. If there are you should look how to fill them with zeroes so this keeps working.

Comment: Trying to implement a similar formula **mean(month1,month2,month3)*((month3-month2)+(month2-month1)/30)** with rolling difference;                                                       `def test(df):
    df = df.sort_values(['ID','DATE'])
    dfgroup = df.groupby(['ID', 'DATE']).AMOUNT.sum()
    dfgroup.name = 'Difference_Amount'
    dfgroup=(dfgroup.rolling(window=3).apply(lambda dfgroup: dfgroup[-1] - dfgroup[0]))/30 
    df = df.merge(dfgroup.reset_index())
    return df`     Somehow, Its still getting me the rolling sum. @Juan C

Comment: ++I tried using `numpy.diff` but due to its limited functionality, I opted against it.